# optimized edge detection code doesn't work on square images - what am I missing (original code given)

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86, cpu-registers

i'm trying to optimize this piece of code in c++ for kirsch edgedetection

however, it seems like it works for any image except those that are same sized (i.e length = width)

I'm not sure why this is happening, I've tried to debug but I keep getting segfault when trying to apply the algorithm

this is the c++ code:

```
void cppkirsch(unsigned char *dOUT,
                      unsigned char *dIN,
                      unsigned height, unsigned width)
{
    /* Kirsch matrices for convolution */
     static int kirsch[8][3][3] = 
          {
            {{  5,  5,  5 }, { -3,  0, -3 }, { -3, -3, -3 }}, /*rotation 1 */
            {{  5,  5, -3 }, {  5,  0, -3 }, { -3, -3, -3 }}, /*rotation 2 */
            {{  5, -3, -3 }, {  5,  0, -3 }, {  5, -3, -3 }}, /*rotation 3 */
            {{ -3, -3, -3 }, {  5,  0, -3 }, {  5,  5, -3 }}, /*rotation 4 */
            {{ -3, -3, -3 }, { -3,  0, -3 }, {  5,  5,  5 }}, /*rotation 5 */
            {{ -3, -3, -3 }, { -3,  0,  5 }, { -3,  5,  5 }}, /*rotation 6 */
            {{ -3, -3,  5 }, { -3,  0,  5 }, { -3, -3,  5 }}, /*rotation 7 */
            {{ -3,  5,  5 }, { -3,  0,  5 }, { -3, -3, -3 }}  /*rotation 8 */
          
          };
    unsigned int size, y, x, lay;

    size = height * width;

    for (lay = 0; lay < 3; lay++) {
        for (y = 1; y < height - 1; ++y) {
            for (x = 1; x < width - 1; x++) {
                int max_sum;
                max_sum = 0;

                /*
                   Perform convolutions for 
                   all 8 masks in succession. Compare and find the one
                   that has the highest value. The one with the
                   highest value is stored into the final bitmap.
                 */
                for (unsigned m = 0; m < 8; ++m) {
                    int sum;
                    sum = 0;
                    /* Convolution part */
                    for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++)
                        for (int l = -1; l < 2; l++) {
                            sum =
                                sum + kirsch[m][k + 1][l + 1] *
                                (int) dIN[lay * size +
                                              (y + k) * width + (x + l)];
                        }
                    if (sum > max_sum)
                        max_sum = sum;
                }
                max_sum = max_sum/8 > 255 ? 255: max_sum/8;
                dOUT[lay * size + y * width + x] = max_sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the version using registers directly:

```
void ssekirch(unsigned char *dOUT,
        unsigned char *dIN, unsigned height,
        unsigned width)
    {

      unsigned int size, i, j, lay;
      unsigned num_of_ints_per_row = width;
      while ((num_of_ints_per_row << 2) % 16)
        num_of_ints_per_row++;
      size = height * width;
      unsigned short *color_rows[3];

      /*
          We divide the 3 colours into 3 separate arrays. 
          We malloc an amount of memory based on number of ints 
          per row x height and set it to 64 bit aligned.
      */
        
        //int storeval =0;
      /*posix_memalign((void **)&color_rows[0], 64,
        sizeof(unsigned short) * num_of_ints_per_row * height);
      posix_memalign((void **)&color_rows[1], 64,
        sizeof(unsigned short) * num_of_ints_per_row * height);
      posix_memalign((void **)&color_rows[2], 64,
        sizeof(unsigned short) * num_of_ints_per_row * height);*/

    #ifdef _WIN32
        void* ret = posix_memalign((void **)&color_rows[0], 64,
        sizeof(unsigned short) * num_of_ints_per_row * height);
        if (ret == nullptr)     throw std::runtime_error("posix memalign");

        ret = posix_memalign((void **)&color_rows[1], 64,
        sizeof(unsigned short) * num_of_ints_per_row * height);
        if (ret == nullptr)     throw std::runtime_error("posix memalign");

        ret = posix_memalign((void **)&color_rows[2], 64,
        sizeof(unsigned short) * num_of_ints_per_row * height);
        if (ret == nullptr)     throw std::runtime_error("posix memalign");

    #else
        int ret = posix_memalign((void **)&color_rows[0], 64,
        sizeof(unsigned short) * num_of_ints_per_row * height);
        if (ret)    throw std::runtime_error("posix memalign");

        ret = posix_memalign((void **)&color_rows[1], 64,
        sizeof(unsigned short) * num_of_ints_per_row * height);
        if (ret)    throw std::runtime_error("posix memalign");

        ret = posix_memalign((void **)&color_rows[2], 64,
        sizeof(unsigned short) * num_of_ints_per_row * height);
        if (ret)    throw std::runtime_error("posix memalign");
    #endif

      /*
          We make the the 3 arrays points to the data that is 
          supplied by the bitmap that is being passed in.
      */
      unsigned short *temp_rows;
      unsigned char *my_data_temp_in = dIN;
      for (lay = 0; lay < 3; lay++) {
        temp_rows = color_rows[lay];
        for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            temp_rows[i * width + j] = my_data_temp_in[i * width + j];
          }
        }
        my_data_temp_in += size;
      }

      /*
          A struct definition which will be used later on to
          assign values.
      */
      typedef union {
        __m128i value;
        unsigned char vector[16];
      } vec_or_val;

      // Loop the 3 arrays
      for (lay = 0; lay < 3; lay++) {
        unsigned short *my_data_in_rmp = color_rows[lay];
        for (i = 1; i < height - 1; ++i) 
        {
          /* 
              Retrieve the following pointers, pointing to the 
              3 consecutive rows od sections upper, middle, lower
          */
          __m128i *upper_row_ptr =
            (__m128i *) & my_data_in_rmp[(i - 1) * num_of_ints_per_row];
          __m128i *middle_row_ptr =
            (__m128i *) & my_data_in_rmp[i * num_of_ints_per_row];
          __m128i *lower_row_ptr =
            (__m128i *) & my_data_in_rmp[(i + 1) * num_of_ints_per_row];

          // Load values
          __m128i upper_row, lower_row, middle_row;
          upper_row  = _mm_load_si128(upper_row_ptr);
          middle_row = _mm_load_si128(middle_row_ptr);
          lower_row  = _mm_load_si128(lower_row_ptr);

          // Retrieve value for next 8 elements

          upper_row_ptr++;
          middle_row_ptr++;
          lower_row_ptr++;

          // Load next 8 values
          __m128i next_upper_row, next_lower_row, next_middle_row;
          next_upper_row  = _mm_load_si128(upper_row_ptr);
          next_middle_row = _mm_load_si128(middle_row_ptr);
          next_lower_row  = _mm_load_si128(lower_row_ptr);

          // Defination of variables which will be used in the loop
          __m128i thrice_upper_row, thrice_middle_row, thrice_lower_row;
          __m128i hex_upper_row,    hex_middle_row,    hex_lower_row;
          __m128i oct_upper_row,    oct_middle_row,    oct_lower_row;

          __m128i next_thrice_upper_row, next_thrice_middle_row, next_thrice_lower_row;
          __m128i next_hex_upper_row,    next_hex_middle_row,    next_hex_lower_row;
          __m128i next_oct_upper_row,    next_oct_middle_row,    next_oct_lower_row;

          __m128i inter_value_2, inter_value_3;
          __m128i inter_value_6, inter_value_8, inter_value_9;

          __m128i upper_shift_once, upper_shift_twice, middle_shift_twice, lower_shift_once, lower_shift_twice;

          /*
              Iterate the array, we are calculating with 16 values at a time
              and every loop we get the values of 2 sums which will later be packed
              and store into the output file.
          */
          for (j = 1; j < width - 17; j = j + 16) {
            __m128i total_sum1, total_sum2;
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {

              // Calculate 3x the value for all 3 rows
              thrice_upper_row  = _mm_add_epi16(upper_row, _mm_add_epi16(upper_row, upper_row));
              thrice_middle_row = _mm_add_epi16(middle_row, _mm_add_epi16(middle_row, middle_row));
              thrice_lower_row  = _mm_add_epi16(lower_row, _mm_add_epi16(lower_row, lower_row));

              // Calculate 5x the value for all 5 rows
              hex_upper_row  = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(upper_row, upper_row), thrice_upper_row);
              hex_middle_row = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(middle_row, middle_row), thrice_middle_row);
              hex_lower_row  = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(lower_row, lower_row), thrice_lower_row);

              // Calculate 8x the value for all 8 rows
              oct_upper_row  = _mm_add_epi16(hex_upper_row, thrice_upper_row);
              oct_middle_row = _mm_add_epi16(hex_middle_row, thrice_middle_row);
              oct_lower_row  = _mm_add_epi16(hex_lower_row, thrice_lower_row);

              // Calculate 3x the value for all 3 rows of the next 8 values
              next_thrice_upper_row  = _mm_add_epi16(next_upper_row, _mm_add_epi16(next_upper_row, next_upper_row));
              next_thrice_middle_row = _mm_add_epi16(next_middle_row, _mm_add_epi16(next_middle_row, next_middle_row));
              next_thrice_lower_row  = _mm_add_epi16(next_lower_row, _mm_add_epi16(next_lower_row, next_lower_row));

              // Calculate 5x the value for all 5 rows of the next 8 values
              next_hex_upper_row  = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(next_upper_row, next_upper_row), next_thrice_upper_row);
              next_hex_middle_row = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(next_middle_row, next_middle_row), next_thrice_middle_row);
              next_hex_lower_row  = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(next_lower_row, next_lower_row), next_thrice_lower_row);

              // Calculate 8x the value for all 8 rows
              next_oct_upper_row  = _mm_add_epi16(next_hex_upper_row, next_thrice_upper_row);
              next_oct_middle_row = _mm_add_epi16(next_hex_middle_row, next_thrice_middle_row);
              next_oct_lower_row  = _mm_add_epi16(next_hex_lower_row, next_thrice_lower_row);

              /*
                 8 versions of intermediate values that corresponds to the offsets between each matrix which
                 will be used as addition or subtraction
                 Intermediate values of 1, 4, 7 need not be calcualated as they refer to 
                 oct_upper_row, oct_middle_row and oct_lower_row respectively which were calculated earlier
              */

              inter_value_2 = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(next_oct_upper_row, 14), _mm_srli_si128(oct_upper_row, 2));
              inter_value_3 = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(next_oct_upper_row, 12), _mm_srli_si128(oct_upper_row, 4));
              inter_value_6 = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(next_oct_middle_row, 12), _mm_srli_si128(oct_middle_row, 4));
              inter_value_8 = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(next_oct_lower_row, 14), _mm_srli_si128(oct_lower_row, 2));
              inter_value_9 = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(next_oct_lower_row, 12), _mm_srli_si128(oct_lower_row, 4));

              // rotation 1
              /*
                { 5,  5,  5},
                {-3,  0, -3},
                {-3, -3, -3}
              */

              // oct_upper_row,                                                                                                     // 5u0
              upper_shift_once    = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(next_hex_upper_row, 14), _mm_srli_si128(hex_upper_row, 2));         // 5u1
              upper_shift_twice   = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(next_hex_upper_row, 12), _mm_srli_si128(hex_upper_row, 4));         // 5u2
              // oct_middle_row,                                                                                                    // 3m0
              middle_shift_twice  = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(next_thrice_middle_row, 12), _mm_srli_si128(thrice_middle_row, 4)); // 3m2
              // oct_lower_row,                                                                                                     // 3l0
              lower_shift_once    = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(next_thrice_lower_row, 14), _mm_srli_si128(thrice_lower_row, 2));   // 3l1
              lower_shift_twice   = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_si128(next_thrice_lower_row, 12), _mm_srli_si128(thrice_lower_row, 4));   // 3l2

              // We zero the starting value of the maximum sum
              __m128i max_sum = _mm_setzero_si128();

              /* 
                  Perform the following operations to get the sum of the first rotation matrix
                  It follows the following formula: 5u0 + 5u1 + 5u2 - 3m0 - 3m2 - 3l0 - 3l1 - 3l2
                  After sum is calulated, we retrieve the max values between max_sum and rotation 
                  matrix's sum and do this for the remaining 7 rotation matrices.
              */

              __m128i sum_rot_1 = _mm_add_epi16(hex_upper_row,  _mm_add_epi16(upper_shift_once, upper_shift_twice));
              sum_rot_1 = _mm_sub_epi16(_mm_sub_epi16(sum_rot_1, thrice_middle_row), middle_shift_twice);
              sum_rot_1 = _mm_sub_epi16(_mm_sub_epi16(sum_rot_1, thrice_lower_row), lower_shift_once);
              sum_rot_1 = _mm_sub_epi16(sum_rot_1, lower_shift_twice);
              max_sum = _mm_max_epi16(max_sum, sum_rot_1); // Get max

              /*
                  From here on, the subsequent sum of the remaining matrices are calclated through
                  addition and subtraction from the previous sum by the offsets
              */

              // rotation 2

              __m128i sum_rot_2 = _mm_add_epi16(oct_middle_row, _mm_sub_epi16(sum_rot_1, inter_value_3));
              max_sum = _mm_max_epi16(max_sum, sum_rot_2);

              // rotation 3

              __m128i sum_rot_3 = _mm_add_epi16(oct_lower_row, _mm_sub_epi16(sum_rot_2, inter_value_2));
              max_sum = _mm_max_epi16(max_sum, sum_rot_3); 

              // rotation 4

              __m128i sum_rot_4 = _mm_add_epi16(inter_value_8, _mm_sub_epi16(sum_rot_3, oct_upper_row));
              max_sum = _mm_max_epi16(max_sum, sum_rot_4); 

              // rotation 5

              __m128i sum_rot_5 = _mm_add_epi16(inter_value_9, _mm_sub_epi16(sum_rot_4, oct_middle_row));
              max_sum = _mm_max_epi16(max_sum, sum_rot_5); 

              // rotation 6

              __m128i sum_rot_6 = _mm_add_epi16(inter_value_6, _mm_sub_epi16(sum_rot_5, oct_lower_row));
              max_sum = _mm_max_epi16(max_sum, sum_rot_6); 

              // rotation 7

              __m128i sum_rot_7 = _mm_add_epi16(inter_value_3, _mm_sub_epi16(sum_rot_6, inter_value_8));
              max_sum = _mm_max_epi16(max_sum, sum_rot_7);

              // rotation 8

              __m128i sum_rot_8 = _mm_add_epi16(inter_value_2, _mm_sub_epi16(sum_rot_7, inter_value_9));
              max_sum = _mm_max_epi16(max_sum, sum_rot_8);
              
              max_sum = _mm_srai_epi16(max_sum, 3);                   // divide each by 8
              max_sum = _mm_max_epi16(max_sum, _mm_setzero_si128());  // max(sum, 0)
              max_sum = _mm_min_epi16(max_sum, _mm_set1_epi16(255));  // min(sum, 255)

              // Store in sum1 and sum2 respectively
              if (k == 0)
                total_sum1 = max_sum;
              else
                total_sum2 = max_sum;

              // Set the variables to prepare for the next loop
              upper_row  = next_upper_row;
              middle_row = next_middle_row;
              lower_row  = next_lower_row;

              upper_row_ptr++;
              middle_row_ptr++;
              lower_row_ptr++;

              next_upper_row = _mm_load_si128(upper_row_ptr);
              next_middle_row = _mm_load_si128(middle_row_ptr);
              next_lower_row = _mm_load_si128(lower_row_ptr);

            }

            /*
            Packing the two rows of values we have computed and write into the
            data out buffer.
            */

            __m128i total_sum =
              _mm_packus_epi16(total_sum1, total_sum2);
            vec_or_val real_sum;
              _mm_store_si128(&real_sum.value, total_sum);

            memcpy_s(&dOUT[lay * size + i * width + j], 16, real_sum.vector, 16);

          }


            /* Cleanup for the remaining pixels that did not get processed earlier */
            //This is the clean up part! 
            //The image size might not be multiple of 16, so we need to deal with the remaining pixels manually.
            //Notice that this code here is pretty much copy pasted from the basis algorithm

          /* Kirsch matrices for convolution */
          static int kirsch[8][3][3] = 
          {
            {{  5,  5,  5 }, { -3,  0, -3 }, { -3, -3, -3 }}, /*rotation 1 */
            {{  5,  5, -3 }, {  5,  0, -3 }, { -3, -3, -3 }}, /*rotation 2 */
            {{  5, -3, -3 }, {  5,  0, -3 }, {  5, -3, -3 }}, /*rotation 3 */
            {{ -3, -3, -3 }, {  5,  0, -3 }, {  5,  5, -3 }}, /*rotation 4 */
            {{ -3, -3, -3 }, { -3,  0, -3 }, {  5,  5,  5 }}, /*rotation 5 */
            {{ -3, -3, -3 }, { -3,  0,  5 }, { -3,  5,  5 }}, /*rotation 6 */
            {{ -3, -3,  5 }, { -3,  0,  5 }, { -3, -3,  5 }}, /*rotation 7 */
            {{ -3,  5,  5 }, { -3,  0,  5 }, { -3, -3, -3 }}  /*rotation 8 */
          
          };


          for (; j < width - 1; j++) {
            int max_sum;
            max_sum = 0;

            /*
            Perform convolutions for
            all 8 masks in succession. Compare and find the one
            that has the highest value. The one with the
            highest value is stored into the final bitmap.
            */
            for (unsigned m = 0; m < 8; ++m) {
              int sum;
              sum = 0;
              /* Convolution part */
              for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++)
                for (int l = -1; l < 2; l++) {
                  sum =
                    sum + kirsch[m][k + 1][l + 1] *
                    (int)dIN[lay * size +
                    (i + k) * width + (j + l)];
                }
              if (sum > max_sum)
                max_sum = sum;
            }
            dOUT[lay * size + i * width + j] = min(max(max_sum / 8, 0), 255);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This is the main if needed:

```
void main() {    
        bmp_read("image.bmp", &header, &data_in);
    
        /* Size of image and output buffer */
        size = header.height * header.width;
        data_out = new unsigned char[3 * size];
        memcpy_s(data_out, 3 * size, data_in, 3 * size);
        printf("Resolution: (%d,%d) -> Size: %d\n", header.height,
               header.width, size);
        for (rep = 0; rep < REP; rep++) {
            ssekirch (data_out, data_in, header.height,
                                   header.width);
        }
        
        bmp_write(argv[2], &header, data_out);
}
```

I'm not sure why I am getting a segfault in my optimized version of the code when I put in an image that is width=length size eg. 200x200. Could someone tell me what am I missing out when I did the conversion from the C++ code to the optimized version?

any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: Even with optimizations enabled you can add debug symbols and use a debugger to try and figure out where the crash happens. I also recommend you build (debug) with compiler sanitizers and use other tools such as Valgrind to help you figure out the likely *undefined behavior* you probably have somewhere.

Comment: Your `posix_memalign` calls are aligning by 64 *bytes*.  That's good because 64-bit alignment like your comment says would only be half an SSE vector.  Also, instead of repeating almost the whole block with a minor difference depending on `_WIN32`, you could factor out the error check to a macro or helper function.  Like `#define MEMALIGN_ERROR(ret) ((ret) == nullptr)` or `ret` that you define once to work around a broken implementation that returns 0 on failure instead of and int errno value.  Or even include the `if() throw` in a macro or wrapper.

Comment: If you want to take input data as one flat array, it would probably be more efficient just to read that (with `_mm_loadu_si128`) instead of allocating memory and copying it inside the processing function.  It might be nice if each color plane was a multiple of the vector width, but you're just adding that stride x1 or x2 to get between them.  Similarly for getting between rows, you don't need an array of pointers, just add the row-stride (to a `char*`, not a `__m128i*`.)  Make some macros or wrapper functions, or possibly pointer local vars maybe. If you do copy, the nested loops can be memcpy